# Restriction that contains a trivial representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, unitary-representations, symmetric-spaces

Let $G$ be a noncompact simple Lie group, and $G'$ a noncompact reductive subgroup of $G$ such that $(G,G')$ is a symmetric pair. If $\pi$ is an infinitely dimensional unitary representation of $G$, does the restriction $\pi|_{G'}$ contains a trivial representation of $G'$ as a subrepresentation? In other words, whether $\mathrm{Hom}_{G'}(1,\pi|_{G'})=\{0\}$ always holds or not?

Comment: The Howe Moore ergodicity says that if $\pi $ is a non-trivial unitary irrep of $G$, the matrix coefficients $g \mapsto (\pi (g) (v),w)$ tend to zero as $g$ tends to infinity. Hence if a vector is fixed under a non-compact subgroup, it will be fixed by the whole group and is therefore zero.

Comment: @Venkataramana That is great! Thank you so much, professor Venkataramana!

Comment: no problem! Glad to be of help